# How to add closing dialog box in flutter

Tags: flutter

How to add a dialog box for exiting app in flutter when user presses back button multiple time. Is it in ondetach process?

Answer (score 0):

wrap your scaffold with WillPopScope widget

then assign that
     onWillPop: _willPopCallback,

Scaffold with WillPopScope Widget will be 
            child: WillPopScope(
            onWillPop: _willPopCallback,
            child: Scaffold(

then create that function

```
DateTime currentBackPressTime;

Future<bool> _willPopCallback() async {
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
if (currentBackPressTime == null || now.difference(currentBackPressTime) > Duration(seconds: 2)) {
  currentBackPressTime = now;


 // Do Things Here
 // Dialog Box
 // Snackbar
 // Toast



   return Future.value(false);
 }
return Future.value(true);
}
```

Hope this will help you